# why changing value without mask doesn't work for pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table and I'm trying to change part of the table to 0. It seems my initial thought did nothing to the table. And then I googled for a solution and found the mask way to do it. But I still wonder why my initial way doesn't work as expected.

My table is

```
            D           E      
C       large small large small
A   B                          
bar one     4     5     6     8
    two     7     6     9     9
foo one     4     1     9     2
    two     0     6     0    11
```

And after doing

```
a='small'
table.loc['bar'].D[a] = 0
print(table.loc['bar'].D[a].values)

mask = table.columns.get_level_values(1) == a
table.loc['bar',mask]=0
print(table.loc['bar'].D[a].values)
```

the output is
[5 6]
[0 0]

I expected the output to be
[0 0]
[0 0]

Comment: can you explain the logic of what you try to achieve?

Comment: i was trying to change values at ['bar','one','small'] and ['bar','two,'small'] to 0s. Just wondering why the first way using index doesn't work.